# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' in angular with an audio source angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I don't know why but in my situation, I got everytimes this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

***I know in angular 8 I have to specify in my viewChild is dynamic***.
To this is my code :

```
  // my var
  @ViewChild('currentMusic', { static: false }) audioRef: ElementRef;


  // my listener
  this.audioRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (data: any) => {
    console.log('timer :' + data.target.currentTime)
  })

  // and in my HTML
  <div hidden *ngIf="(audio$ | async); let m">
    <audio #currentMusic autoplay>
      <source [src]="baseUrl + m.file.url" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
```

So when when I display the page, my `(audio$ | async)` is null, I have to select a link to play the music. I must use only one player. Thank you if you have the solution

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do not use the async inside *ngIf because it will not work with the ViewChild properly :

### Solution :

- Catching the event timeupdate directly from the audio element (with async):

**HTML :**

```
  <audio #currentMusic (timeupdate)="onTimeUpdate($event)" autoplay>
     <source [src]="baseUrl + m.file.url" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
```

**Typescript :**

```
  onTimeUpdate(event: any) {
    console.log('timer :' , event.target.currentTime)
  }
```

PS : works for me without using the | async.